# How to add a WMS layer on Cesium Globe?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, cesium

I downloaded Cesium Java Script library for creating 3D Globes from "http://cesium.agi.com/".
Also I found that, they are using Bing satellite map as default. But I need to display layer from My Geoserver. I am very new to this Java Script library.

Can you please tell me , How to add a WMS Layer from Geoserver on the Cesium globe? 
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Is it not throwing proxy error? If so, how did you overcome it? Please provide some hint to overcome the proxy issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ya I got It...
 Here is the solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <script src="Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <style>
  @import url(Cesium/Widgets/CesiumWidget/CesiumWidget.css);

  #cesiumContainer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
  }


</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
  <script>

var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');
var url='http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms'; //Geoserver URL
var layers = widget.scene.globe.imageryLayers;
    layers.removeAll();
    layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url : url,        
        layers: 'GIS_Demo'// Here just give layer name
    }));

Sandcastle.finishedLoading();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Again one more doubt, How can I add titled layers?

Comment: They have a tutorial listing/demonstrating the various imagery layers: https://cesiumjs.org/2013/01/04/Cesium-Imagery-Layers-Tutorial/, specifically: https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/UrlTemplateImageryProvider.html